# Taking derivative with quotient rule and sums

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to differentiate this with respect to $\eta$ but am having some difficulty.

\begin{equation}
g_0(1,\eta) = \frac{\frac{3\eta}{(\eta_c - \eta)} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}kA_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}\right)^k}{4\eta}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g_0'(1,\eta) = \frac{(4\eta)\left(\frac{3\eta_c}{(\eta_c - \eta)^2}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}k^2A_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}\right)^{k-1}\right)-\left(\frac{3\eta}{(\eta_c - \eta)} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}kA_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}\right)^k\right)(4)}{(4\eta)^2}
\end{equation}

Does this look right? When I continue from here, it just does not seem like anything is cancelling out or anything like that, so I want to make sure what I am doing looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\require{cancel}
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\eta}g(1, \eta) &=& \frac{1}{4}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\eta} \left[ \frac{3\cancel{\eta}}{\cancel{\eta}(\eta_c - \eta)} + \sum_{k=1}^4 k A_k \frac{\eta^k}{\eta \eta_c^k}\right]  \\
&=& \frac{3}{4} \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\eta} \frac{1}{\eta_c - \eta} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{k A_k}{\eta_c^k} \frac{{\rm d}\eta^{k-1}}{{\rm d}\eta} \\
&=& \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{(\eta_c - \eta)^2} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{k(k-1) A_k}{\eta_c^k}\eta^{k - 2} \\
&=& \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{(\eta_c - \eta)^2} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{k(k-1) A_k}{\eta_c^2}\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}\right)^{k - 2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Wow, thanks! As a follow-up, assuming that $x=\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}$, how can I get rid of all $\eta$'s and just express them as x?

Comment: The first term becomes

$$
\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\eta_c^2(1 - \eta/\eta_c)^2} = \frac{3}{4\eta_c^2} \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}
$$

the last one is the same except replace the factor in parenthesis by $x$

Comment: Did you accidentally lose a $\eta$? The last term in first and second lines. In first line, there is an $\eta$ in denominator. Where is it on next line? After the $d \eta$ shouldnt there also be an $\eta$ in denominator? It looks like you dropped it?

Comment: @JacksonHart Yes I did! Sorry about that. Fixed